# Get user info on g+ button javascript callback

Tags: google-plus

How do I get the user details, atleast the user email address once the user shares the page using G+ button on my website. I can see that the callback function is getting called when a user is successfully sharing the page on Google plus. Even the page gets post information when the user is sharing the data, but I am not sure how to I get that info inside the scope of the function to make a save through ajax or any other way.